# How can I get UILabel on a custom table view cell?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

In my custom cell there is a `UILabel` and one `UIButton`. Whenever I click on that `UIButton` the `UILabel`'s height is increased as per content of the label.

The problem is that how can I get that `UILabel` that is a subview of a cell. Every cell contains a label and a button but only that `UILabel` is increased that the cell button is clicked, others remain as they are.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to have to give us more to go on than that - post some code to illustrate what you currently have and explain what you are trying to achieve. One question I have straight away is "Why are you trying to get to the UILabel?" - you should have methods on the cell that controls the labels and so you should send messages to the cell which will control the label.

Comment: There is many subviews on customcell but i want only particular label height increase as per button click(whenever content is more than click on more button label and cell's height increased.I success with particular cell height but on that cell particular label's height is not increase)

Comment: My comment still stands. You should have a method on the cell that is called to signal that you want the height of the label to increase and the cell will handle changing that. The cell 'owns' the label that is on it, so it should be responsible for changing the height. Without adding some of your code showing your cell, I can't advise more detailed than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through all `subview`s in the cell and see which one is a `UILabel`:

```
for(UIView *v in [cell subviews])
{
    if([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
       //you can put more checks to see if height is to be increased/decreased
       [v setFrame:CGRectMake(origin.x,origin.y,width,height)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you have need to assign TAG for every component..

Answer (score 0):

Try bind the method to your button may work for you.

```
-(void)buttonClick:(id)sender {


UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[sender superview];
NSArray *subviews=[cell subviews];
for (int i=0; i<[subviews count]; i++) {
    id object=[subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    if([object isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
        //do stuff here
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to assign the `tag` property to the labels. That way in your button action method you can find the relevant label. For example:

```
- (void) myButtonAction: (UIButton *) sender
{
    UILabel *theLabel = (UILabel *) [sender.superview viewWithTag: MYLABELTAG];
    // Do something with theLabel
}
```

What this code does is finds the label in the same view as the button is in.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a short example on how to get labels from tablecells here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9864169/407488

But i think what you want is to increase all labels in all cells at once? Then just use `reloadData` and change a member variable before calling it (when touching the button). You read that member in your `cellForRow:` code and assign the height appropriate.